# Ten students from which three are first year, four second and three third year of study are in the elevator of the new faculty building.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Ten students from which three are first year, four second and three third year of study are in the elevator of the new faculty building. Suppose every random student comes out on one of the 5 floors, with all possible outcomes equally probable. If we know that at least one student came out on each floor, what is the probability of that no two students of same year came out on the same floor?

This is obviously conditional probability. I put

$A $= { at least one student came out on each floor }  ,

$ B $= { no two students of same year came out on the same floor } ,

and I have to calculate $P ( B | A) $. I have calculated that 
$|B \cap A| = 5*4*3*5*4*3*2*5*4*3 - 5*4*3*2*4*3*2*1*4*3*2 $
 (first student of first year has $5$ floors as a option, second of first year $ 4$, third $3$, first of second year $5 $ etc. and subtract that with case where one of five floors is empty, now first student of first year has $4$ floors to choose etc.). Is that right thinking?

Comment: The phrasing of the question is ambiguous. Is it asking for the probability that **no two students from the same year got off on the same floor**, given that at least one student got off on every floor?

Comment: @kccu yes, sorry for not being clear about question. Why extra 5?

Comment: No extra $5$, I see now you are accounting for which floor is empty. Yes, this line of reasoning looks good.

Comment: @kccu thanks :)

Comment: Your way seems ok.